# Skype "home unavailable" with Internet access

Tags: windows-7, skype

My Skype worked under Windows 7 with no problems two hours ago. I did not change any settings or configuration. However, it does not work anymore: "Skype home unavailable," it says, although I can access the Internet, download my e-mails etc.

My status is never "Online" and all my contacts are also offline (even "Echo / Sound test service").

[image]

I tried rebooting, no success. I tried updating and resetting the Internet Explorer as advised here: http://jaypeeee.blogspot.cz/2014/05/how-to-fix-skype-home-unavailable-error.html, no success. I checked my firewall and it seems to be OK (but honestly I do not know what to look for).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently issues with Skype servers:

http://heartbeat.skype.com/2015/09/skype_presence_issues.html?cm_mmc=SMTW_7001B1-Skype%20-%20Support

Not much you can do at the moment, except use the web version: https://web.skype.com

Comment: Wow, I really did not expect that, thank you a lot! It is great you provided this link!

Comment: I work for the IT department for an organisation, and literally 10 minutes ago users were complaining they cannot log into Skype. I then came across this post - so thank you! :)